# Error in newMediaItemResults in Google Photos API

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, google-photos-api

I was able get the upload token and a 200 status code on `batchCreate`. However, the detailed response was this;

```
{
  "newMediaItemResults": [
    {
      "uploadToken": "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",
      "status": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Below is the code for the upload function;

```
uploadImages(images, token) {
        const promises = Array.from(images).map(image => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('media-binary-data', image);
            console.log(formData);
            return axios.post(`${UPLOAD_URL}`, formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream",
                    'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': '',
                    'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': "raw",
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                },

            }).then((response) => {
                return axios.post('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate',
                    {
                        "newMediaItems": [
                            {
                                "description": "item-description",
                                "simpleMediaItem": {
                                    "uploadToken": response.data
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                        },

                    })
            })
        });

        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload the image files to Google Photo using Google Photo API using axios with Javascript.
- `images` of `const promises = Array.from(images).map(image => {` is `document.getElementById("###").files` from `<input type="file" id="files" name="file" multiple>`.

### Modification points:

- From your error message, I thought that the files might not have been able to be correctly uploaded.

  - In this modified script, `FormData()` is not used.
- At the method of "mediaItems.batchCreate", after the multiple files were uploaded, their files can be used for one API call.
- The content type of the request body of `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate` is `application/json`. So in this case, please use `JSON.stringify` to the request body.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. In this modification, as a sample situation, tha tags of HTML are added.

### Modified script:

#### HTML side:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" multiple>
<input type="button" onclick="run()" value="ok">
```

#### Javascript side:

Please set your access token to `token`.

```
function uploadImages(images, token) {
  const promises = Array.from(images).map(image => {
    return new Promise(r => {
      axios.post("https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads", image, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream",
          'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': image.name,
          'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': "raw",
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        r({description: "item-description", simpleMediaItem: {fileName: image.name, uploadToken: response.data}});
      });
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then(e => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate',
        JSON.stringify({newMediaItems: e}),
        {headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`},
      })
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
    });
  });
}

// This function is run.
function run() {

  const token = "###";  // Please set your access token.

  const files = document.getElementById("files").files;
  uploadImages(files, token)
  .then(e => console.log(e))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your access token can be used for uploading the image files to Google Photo using Google Photo API. Please be careful this.
- In this modified script, as a sample situation, tha tags of HTML are added. In my environment, I could confirm that the above modified script worked. But I think that above HTML tags might be different from your actual situation. So please modify above script for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Upload media](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media)
- [Method: mediaItems.batchCreate](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/batchCreate)